# Check if an object is type or sub-type of T, T is stored as String

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, dynamic-cast

I am facing a little problem when i try to check whether an object is a sub-class of another. I am aware of the `is_base_of`, `is_same` methods but they do not fulfill my needs. Here is the thing:

I have a list of polymorphic objects (Component) `std::list<Component*>`, and a bunch of template methods that act on these containers.
`getComponent<T>(), getComponents<T>(), getComponentOfType<T>() ...`

1. `T* getComponent():` Retrieves any component of type T from the container if exists. Otherwise, returns `nullptr`.

> It deals with an **object** and a Type **`T`**: I used **boost::typeindex::type_index**.

```
template<typename T >
T* getComponent(){
    for( Component* c : container ){
        if( boost::typeindex::type_id_runtime(*c).pretty_name() == boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<T>().pretty_name() ){
            return c;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

2. `T* getComponentOfType()` Retrieves any component of **type** or __sub-type of `T` from the container if exists. Otherwise, returns `nullptr`.

> It deals with an **object** and a type **`T`**

```
template< typename T >
T* getComponentOfType(){
   for( Component* c : container ){
      T* c2 = dynamic_cast<T*>(c);
      if( c2 != nullptr ){
         return c2;
      }
   }
   return nullptr;
}
```

3. `std::list<T*> getComponents():` and `std::list<T*> getComponentsOfType()` are a list-version of respectively `getComponent()` and `getComponentOfType()`.

**However**, the remaining methods require to deal with **object** and **object**, or **object** and **string**.

For example, a method called `bool check_singleton(Component* c)`, checks if the container has or not a component of type or sub-type of `c`,

**note that:** `c is polymorphic` and `check_singleton` uses a list of string, containing all components that must be singletons. `std::list<std::string>`

Can be expressed as follow:

> `object inherits "ClassName"` ??

Thank you.
Cordially.

Comment: Not really. Templates are evaluated during compilation time. std::strings cannot be read during compilation only in runtime. You may can look at `boost::mpl` for having lists of types.

Comment: `getComponentOfType()` is buggy as it inspects only first argument and UB for empty list.

Comment: *`bool check_singleton(Component* c)`* and *"`check_singleton` uses a list of string"* seems to contradict.

Comment: @Jarod42 1. For the `getComponentOfType`, Yes i failed the else, the return `nullptr` should be outside the `for` loop.

Comment: @Jarod42 Any component can be singleton or not, and when a component is singleton ( i.e Its type ). it has an entry in a special container `std::list<string>`. This container holds all component that must be singleton. And the `check_singleton`, will compare a given component to the container of components based on the singleton_container.

Comment: @Hayt I will check that , thx

Comment: Why are you comparing type names instead of type info? Why do you have a list of singleton types as strings? Is the list determined at run time?

Comment: @n.m. No, it is determined at compile-time. You're saying that storing then comparing type info would be way better ?!

Comment: ((1)). You are doing something like `type_id_runtime(*c).pretty_name() == type_id_with_cvr<T>().pretty_name()`. It seems that `type_id_runtime(*c) == type_id_with_cvr<T>()` does the same job and is shorter and does not depend on details of pretty naming. ((2)) If you need to check that an object X is of class that inherits class Y, why involve strings at all? You can store a bunch of functions generated from `template <type T> bool is_of_runtime_type(Component* c) { return dynamic_cast<T*>(c) != nullptr;}` or equivalent.

Comment: @n.m. ((1)) That is true, did not notice that.
((2)) It will only cover a part of The Components list ( built-in Components ).
As i am using this as a library, new `user-Component` can be created. 
Those components will not have their own `is_of_runtime_type` method, unless the user manually creates it.

Comment: I was using the Qt-MOC to check this before converting to pure C++ ( free-qt code ). Sure, there was a hole system behind, with MACROs, generated moc_files etc. and the procedure was based on "String", that is why i thought it may be possible,

example: 
`T::staticMetaObject.inherits( "ComponentType")`  , 
`c->metaObject().inherits( T::staticMetaObject.className() )`

Comment: `is_of_runtime_type` is a template defined in some header. The users will need to register their type one way or another. If they can call `register_singleton_name("mytype")`, they can also call `register_singleton_checker(is_of_runtime_type<mytype>)`.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, it is somehow like that.
Thanks for the help. I'll do it that way.